# solve for $x$ and $y$ in the following equation $x^2 +y^2 -3=3xy$ and $2x^2 +y^2 =6$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve for $x$ and $y$ in the following equations: $x^2 +y^2 -3=3xy$ and $2x^2 +y^2 =6$. I made $y^2$ the subject of the formula in eqn 2.
This gives $y^2 = 6 -2x^2$.
I substitute this into the first eqn.
This gives $x^2+3xy -3$. There's where am stuck.
 Can someone pull me out.

Comment: From the second equation,  WLOG $$\sqrt2x=\sqrt6\cos t,y=\sqrt6\sin t$$ Put these value sin the first and divide by $\cos^2t$

Comment: Pls can you explain further

Comment: Please follow the steps and let me know where you are stuck

Answer (score 0):

Hint....From what you have obtained, $x^2+3xy=3$ make $y$ the subject and substitute this into the equation $2x^2+y^2=6$ and you will obtain a quadratic in $x^2$

Answer (score 0):

multiplying the first equation by $-1$ and adding to the second we get
$$x^2+3xy=3$$ thus $$y=\frac{3-x^2}{3x}$$ if $$x\ne 0$$ and you can eliminate $y$

Answer (score 0):

If 
$$
  \begin{cases}
    2x^2+y^2=6\\
x^2+y^2=3+3xy \\ 
  \end{cases}
$$
then by setting $x^2=a$, $y^2=b$
$$
  \begin{cases}
     2a+b=6 \\
    a+b=3+3xy \\
  \end{cases}
$$
Hence, by Cramer's rule (of linear algebra)
$$
\begin{cases}
a=x^2=3-3xy & (1)\\
b=y^2=6xy & (2)
\end{cases}
$$
Hence, by (2) $y=0$ or $y=6x$. Plug it into (1) yields 
$$
x^2=3-3x\cdot0\qquad\text{or}\qquad
x^2=3-3x\cdot6x
$$
Hence $(x,y)=(\pm\sqrt{3},0)$ or $(x,y)=(\pm\frac{\sqrt{57}}{19},\pm\frac{6\sqrt{57}}{19})$.